# HD and SD toggling for JW player

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have the following code in JW player :

```
file: '{/literal}{$video_data.url_flv}{literal}',
```

How can  add SD LABEL and HD LABEL to the file:

```
{/literal}{$video_data.url_flv}{literal}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't comment on your post due to insufficiant reputation i'll just post this here.

I think if you read this article: [support jwplayer hd quality toggling](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling)

You will see what you need to do.